# Items in Table does not match to specific JSON in another Table: PHP?

Tags: php, json

I'm new to php and am trying to implement a way to output data from one Table to correspond to a JSON object in another table.

Currently this is the main table:

[image]

This is the second table containing items that is suppose to correspond to each "id" in the main table:

[image]

For example, in the second table, `culturevillage_id` corresponds to the `id` in the main table. Therefore, the JSON with `id = 1` should output 6 items.

Here's the code I tried to implement:

```
$sql = "select * from main_table";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$jsonData = array();
$rowCount = $result->num_rows;
$index = 1;

while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sqlnew = "select * from secondary_table where culturevillage_id=" .$row['id']. "" ;
    $resultnew = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlnew) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $jsonData = array();
    $rowCountnew = $resultnew->num_rows;
    $indexnew = 1;
    //echo $rowCount;
    if ($rowCountnew >0)
    {
        while($rownew =mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultnew))
        {
            $imageString[$indexnew] = array("normal_res_link" => $rownew['normal_res_link']);

            ++$indexnew;

        }
    }

    echo '"item'.$index.'":';
    echo json_encode(array("id" => intval($row['id']),"english_name" => $row['english_name'], "vietnamese_name" => $row['vietnamese_name'], "images" =>$imageString));
    if ($rowCount != $index)
    {
        echo ',';
    }
    ++$index;
}

echo ' }'
```

However, I get the following output:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "id": 1,
        "english_name": "Ben Thanh Market",
        "vietnamese_name": "Cho Ben Thanh",
        "images": {
            "1": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "2": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "3": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "4": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "5": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "6": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1
            }
        }
    },
    "item2": {
        "id": 3,
        "english_name": "One Pillar Pagoda",
        "vietnamese_name": "Chua Mot Cot",
        "images": {
            "1": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "2": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "3": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "4": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "5": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "6": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            }
        }
    },
    "item3": {
        "id": 4,
        "english_name": "Hung King Temple",
        "vietnamese_name": "Den Hung"
        "images": {
            "1": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=4"
            },
            "2": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=4"
            },
            "3": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "4": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1""
            },
            "5": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            },
            "6": {
                "normal_res_link": "id=1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `item1` JSON for the `images` field is correct, there should be 6 items. However for `item2`, the output grabs from `item1`'s image data, and for `item3`, it grabs the remaining 4 items from `item1`'s image data.

The correct output should be that `item2`'s images field should be empty and `item3`'s images field should only contain 2 data in according with the data in the secondary table.

I know my implementation is wrong somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why are you not using JOIN here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just not initialize your `$imageString` array;

Add `$imageString = array();` before anything push to it.

```
$imageString = array(); // <--
if ($rowCountnew >0)
{
    while($rownew =mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultnew))
    {
```

---

*Offtopic:*

1. *Try also following query:*

   `select s.* from secondary_table s join main_table t on t.id=s.culturevillage_id`
2. *You should use `json_encode` for whole data, not try to generate it by parts.*

---

```
$sql = "select * from secondary_table s join main_table t on t.id=s.culturevillage_id" ;
$q = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$jsonData = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
  if (!isset($jsonData[$q['culturevillage_id']]) {
    $jsonData[$q['culturevillage_id']] = $row;
    unset($jsonData[$q['culturevillage_id']]['normal_res_link']);
    $jsonData[$q['culturevillage_id']]['images'] = array();
  }
  $jsonData[$q['culturevillage_id']]['images'][] = $row['normal_res_link'];
}
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: I added the suggested code and it seems to work partially..`item3` does not output the items with id=1, but `item2` still outputs 6 items even though it should be empty

Comment: Just lift it up to appropriate place.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to this, just learning and not sure what you mean, I replaced `$sqlnew = "select * from secondary_table where culturevillage_id=" .$row['id']. "" ;` with `$sqlnew = "select s.* from secondary_table s join main_table t on t.id=s.culturevillage_id=" .$row['id']. "" ;` but now no output for `item3` and `item3`'s data is joined to `item1`

Comment: no need to `$row['id']`, no need to make first query at all, just raw query from my suggestion does same thing, like your two. You should iterate them and separate by `culturevillage_id`.

Comment: can you provide the suggestion solution using my php code?..I don't believe I wrote the code efficiently...I feel I would understand better if I knew where you place your suggestion in my code?..I learn better through specific examples..thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131882/discussion-between-pangu-and-vp-arth).

Answer (score 1):

I have a different view, you have used a loop to get every single id from one table and then you are trying another query for doing the same. You need to use FOREIGN_KEY in sql while creating the table, and then you will be able to do it only in one single query without any loop. For example I have created a message system through this.

You can check this out

These are the tables and you can see the connections- 
[image]

Now check out this one, this is how you create foreign Key for multiple tables-

[image]

Now when You have to write an SQL query for it You will write it lie this -

[image]

You can See that this query is using three table in one query by reference.

Comment: This `conversation` table will hurt when you will want to implement more than 2-user conversation. It's much better to use another `conversation_participants` table with `(cr_id, user_id, ...)` structure

Comment: [Example](https://habrastorage.org/files/5c5/edd/69a/5c5edd69a5ae451c81c314f2525ecad6.png)

Comment: @vp_arth Thank you so much , but I was helping for for foreign keys only. But thank you for your solution :)